# Custom 404 error page is generating a 500 error

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, errordocument, custom-error-handling

For security reasons, I am making it so that all php files generate a 404 error, then using a custom 404 error page, like so:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[\ /?].*HTTP/
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=404,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /error.html
```

Any php script I go to returns a custom 404 error page, as I would like, but below that it says:

> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

But when I go to a page that actually doesn't exist (lets say `http://localhost/Hello/world.html`) I get the error page I want.

I'm confused, what am I doing wrong. Also, I would like to be able to use a php pagefor my custom `ErrorDocument`, but I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: check the server's error log to get details on the 500.

Comment: It just says something about exceeding the limit of internal redirects, but I don't know what that means

Answer (score 0):

You should try a redirect match:

```
RedirectMatch 404 ".*\.php"
```

This will pass the Not Found Error, and throw the appropriate `ErrorDocument`.

Comment: It's not working, but maybe it's just me interpreting it wrong. Are you saying to replace the thing that generates the 404 (`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[\ /?].*HTTP/    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=404,L]`) with that?

Comment: Yes, because rewrites (`mod_rewrite`) and redirects are two different things. You should only have the `RedirectMatch` and the `ErrorDocument`.